# Identify the string that does not exists in another string using regex and C#

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to capture a string that does not contains in another string.

```
string searchedString = " This is my search string";
string subsetofSearchedString = "This is my";
```

My output should be "Search string". I would like to go with only regex so that I can handle complex strings.

The below is the code that I have tried so far and I am not successful.

```
 Match match = new Regex(subsetofSearchedString ).Match(searchedString );
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(match.Value))
 {
      UnmatchedString= UnmatchedString.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty);
 }
```

Update : The above code is not working for the below texts.

```
text1 = 'Property Damage (2015 ACURA)' Exposure Added Automatically for IP:Claimant DriverLoss Reserve Line :Property DamageReserve Amount $ : STATIP Role(s): Owner, DriverExposure Owner :Jaimee Watson_csr Author:
text2 = 'Property Damage (2015 ACURA)' Exposure Added Automatically for IP:Claimant DriverLoss Reserve Line :Property DamageReserve Amount $ : STATIP Role(s): Owner, Driver

Match match = new Regex(text2).Match(text1);
```

Comment: So you want to get the parts of a string that does not match a regex pattern?

Comment: How does your current code not work?

Comment: From your desired output, do you also want the first letter to be capitalised?

Comment: Shouldn't the output also include the leading space in `searchedString`?

Comment: @Sweeper  I just updated my question with the  texts that were not working.

Comment: Which is the search string and which is the subset?

Comment: @NetMage Match match = new Regex(text2).Match(text1);

Comment: If your `text1` contains regular expression meta characters, you need to use `Regex.Escape` to escape them, but I assumed you wanted to be able to use regex in the subset since that's what you stated. Your `text1` should be `"'Property Damage \(2015 ACURA\)' Exposure Added Automatically for IP:Claimant DriverLoss Reserve Line :Property DamageReserve Amount \$ : STATIP Role\(s\): Owner, Driver"`

Comment: The problem is that the Regex constructor takes a regular expression string as its parameter. You are instead passing in a string which is not a regular expression. For this case, you just need `String.Contains`.

Comment: @CallumWatkins True, but `Contains` won't help solve the issue of removing matches.

Comment: @NetMage the code to remove the matches is already working fine in this example, `String.Replace` is not the problem here.

Comment: @CallumWatkins And how exactly would `Contain` yield a `match.Value` to use in `Replace`?

Comment: @CallumWatkins  String contains is going to be tough to handle the complex strings. But I see what you are saying. probably I might have to use escape characters to pass the whole text as a valid pattern.  Another regex again to add escape characters ? :-(
Ex : "Property Damage \\(2015 ACURA\\)"

Comment: @NetMage because you already know what `match.Value` will be, it will just be the exact same value that you are searching for in the first place, i.e. `subsetofSearchedString`

Comment: @Bendram What is the point of all the fooling around with `Match` when `Regex.Replace` will do it in one step?

Comment: @CallumWatkins And the question says "I would like to go with only regex so that I can handle complex strings."

Comment: @Bendram could you give us a little bit more context on the "complex strings" you mention

Comment: @NetMage I understand that this was in the question, but it may be the case that there is a misunderstanding of the way regular expressions work and I just want to make sure that regex is the right way to go. In the example in the question there is no need for regex at all.

Comment: @ NetMage Hey I din't read your earlier text .Let me quickly try Regex.Escape and see if that works out and fixing the text1 part as well.

Comment: @NetMage I ended up using contains and then replaced the text with an empty string. Regex wasn't working because of  presence of meta characters.

Comment: Why bother with `String.Contains`? Why not just use `String.Replace`?

Comment: @NetMage I have to perform some actions only if the string contains and then doing String.Replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Split`:

```
var ans = Regex.Split(searchedString, subsetofSearchedString);
```

If you want the answer as a single string minus the subset, you can join it:

```
var ansjoined = String.Join("", ans);
```

Replacing with `String.Empty` will also work:

```
var ans = Regex.Replace(searchedString, subsetOfSearchedString, String.Empty);
```

Comment: This answers my original question and hence accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

Regex wasn't working for me because of the presence of metacharacters in my string. Regex.Escape did not help me  with the comparison.

String Contains worked like a charm here

```
if (text1.Contains(text2))
   {  
      status = TestResult.Pass;
      text1= text1.Replace(text2, string.Empty);
   }
```